# Heroku deploy detectron2 could not find a version

Tags: python, flask, heroku, detectron

i'm trying to deploy my python flask app to heroku. when i'm pushing to repository to heroku that's occurs

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
detectron2==0.6 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for detectron2==0.6
```

i created requirement.txt and Procfile files.
what should i do?